# What's a good C memory allocator for embedded systems?

Tags: c, embedded, lua, malloc, allocation

I have an single threaded, embedded application that allocates and deallocates lots and lots of small blocks (32-64b). The perfect scenario for a cache based allocator. And although I could TRY to write one it'll likely be a waste of time, and not as well tested and tuned as some solution that's already been on the front lines.

So what would be the best allocator I could use for this scenario?

Note: I'm using a Lua Virtual Machine in the system (which is the culprit of 80+% of the allocations), so I can't trivially refactor my code to use stack allocations to increase allocation performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some research on this very topic recently, as we had an issue with memory fragmentation. In the end we decided to stay with GNU libc's implementation, and add some application-level memory pools where necessary. There were other allocators which had better fragmentation behavior, but we weren't comfortable enough with them replace malloc globally. GNU's has the benefit of a long history behind it.

In your case it seems justified; assuming you can't fix the VM, those tiny allocations are very wasteful. I don't know what your whole environment is, but you might consider wrapping the calls to malloc/realloc/free on just the VM so that you can pass it off to a handler designed for small pools.

Comment: Used Loki for this purpose, all worked out great, and it took very little time

Comment: Chris, would you be willing to share the code for the modified version of glibc malloc with the memory pools?

Answer (score 10):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I just want to share very efficient memory allocator for embedded systems I've recently found and tested: [https://github.com/dimonomid/umm_malloc](http://goo.gl/XAiNHy)

This is a memory management library specifically designed to work with the ARM7, personally I use it on PIC32 device, but it should work on any 16- and 8-bit device (I have plans to test in on 16-bit PIC24, but I haven't tested it yet)

I was seriously beaten by fragmentation with default allocator: my project often allocates blocks of various size, from several bytes to several hundreds of bytes, and sometimes I faced 'out of memory' error. My PIC32 device has total 32K of RAM, and 8192 bytes is used for heap. At the particular moment there is more than 5K of free memory, but default allocator has maximum non-fragmented memory block just of about 700 bytes, because of fragmentation. This is too bad, so I decided to look for more efficient solution.

I already was aware of some allocators, but all of them has some limitations (such as block size should be a power or 2, and starting not from 2 but from, say, 128 bytes), or was just buggy. Every time before, I had to switch back to the default allocator.

But this time, I'm lucky: I've found this one: http://hempeldesigngroup.com/embedded/stories/memorymanager/

When I tried this memory allocator, in exactly the same situation with 5K of free memory, it has more than 3800 bytes block! It was so unbelievable to me (comparing to 700 bytes), and I performed hard test: device worked heavily more than 30 hours. No memory leaks, everything works as it should work.
I also found this allocator in the FreeRTOS repository: http://svnmios.midibox.org/listing.php?repname=svn.mios32&path=%2Ftrunk%2FFreeRTOS%2FSource%2Fportable%2FMemMang%2F&rev=1041&peg=1041# , and this fact is an additional evidence of stability of umm_malloc.
So I completely switched to umm_malloc, and I'm quite happy with it.

I just had to change it a bit: configuration was a bit buggy when macro UMM_TEST_MAIN is not defined, so, I've created the github repository (the link is at the top of this post). Now, user dependent configuration is stored in separate file umm_malloc_cfg.h

I haven't got deeply yet in the algorithms applied in this allocator, but it has very detailed explanation of algorithms, so anyone who is interested can look at the top of the file umm_malloc.c . At least, "binning" approach should give huge benefit in less-fragmentation: http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html

I believe that anyone who needs for efficient memory allocator for microcontrollers, should at least try this one.

Comment: this is the best answer here. Thanks for the link! If you are interested, check out my memory manager also: https://github.com/cloudformdesign/tinymem  I've designed it to handle fragmentation :)

Answer (score 9):

In a past project in C I worked on, we went down the road of implementing our own memory management routines for a library ran on a wide range of platforms including embedded systems.  The library also allocated and freed a large number of small buffers.  It ran relatively well and didn't take a large amount of code to implement.  I can give you a bit of background on that implementation in case you want to develop something yourself.

The basic implementation included a set of routines that managed buffers of a set size.  The routines were used as wrappers around malloc() and free().   We used these routines to manage allocation of structures that we frequently used and also to manage generic buffers of set sizes.  A structure was used to describe each type of buffer being managed.  When a buffer of a specific type was allocated, we'd malloc() the memory in blocks (if a list of free buffers was empty).  IE, if we were managing 10 byte buffers, we might make a single malloc() that contained space for 100 of these buffers to reduce fragmentation and the number of underlying mallocs needed.

At the front of each buffer would be a pointer that would be used to chain the buffers in a free list.  When the 100 buffers were allocated, each buffer would be chained together in the free list.  When the buffer was in use, the pointer would be set to null.  We also maintained a list of the "blocks" of buffers, so that we could do a simple cleanup by calling free() on each of the actual malloc'd buffers.

For management of dynamic buffer sizes, we also added a size_t variable at the beginning of each buffer telling the size of the buffer.  This was then used to identify which buffer block to put the buffer back into when it was freed.  We had replacement routines for malloc() and free() that did pointer arithmetic to get the buffer size and then to put the buffer into the free list.  We also had a limit on how large of buffers we managed.  Buffers larger than this limit were simply malloc'd and passed to the user.  For structures that we managed, we created wrapper routines for allocation and freeing of the specific structures.

Eventually we also evolved the system to include garbage collection when requested by the user to clean up unused memory.  Since we had control over the whole system, there were various optimizations we were able to make over time to increase performance of the system.  As I mentioned, it did work quite well.

Answer (score 6):

Although its been some time since I asked this, my final solution was to use LoKi's SmallObjectAllocator it work great. Got rid off all the OS calls and improved the performance of my Lua engine for embedded devices. Very nice and simple, and just about 5 minutes worth of work!

Answer (score 5):

Since [version 5.1](http://www.lua.org/versions.html#5.1), [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) has allowed a [custom allocator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_Alloc) to be set when [creating new states](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_newstate).

Answer (score 3):

I'd just also like to add to this even though it's an old thread. In an embedded application if you can analyze your memory usage for your application and come up with a max number of memory allocation of the varying sizes usually the fastest type of allocator is one using memory pools. In our embedded apps we can determine all allocation sizes that will ever be needed during run time. If you can do this you can completely eliminate heap fragmentation and have very fast allocations. Most these implementations have an overflow pool which will do a regular malloc for the special cases which will hopefully be far and few between if you did your analysis right.

Comment: very good point! I forgot about this, but it's exactly what I did when I was programming on the GameBoy

Answer (score 2):

I have used the 'binary buddy' system to good effect under vxworks. Basically, you portion out your heap by cutting blocks in half to get the smallest power of two sized block to hold your request, and when blocks are freed, you can make a pass up the tree to merge blocks back together to mitigate fragmentation.  A google search should turn up all the info you need.

Answer (score -1):

I am writing a C memory allocator called tinymem that is intended to be able to defragment the heap, and re-use memory. Check it out:

https://github.com/vitiral/tinymem

Note: this project has been discontinued to work on the rust implementation:

https://github.com/vitiral/defrag-rs

Also, I had not heard of umm_malloc before. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be able to deal with fragmentation, but it definitely looks useful. I will have to check it out.